# MongoDB - $lookup and $aggregate in 2 collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have two collections like this :

**1st collection name is Promotions:**

```
    {
     "_id": "A019283847466",
     "code": "AAA",
     "aliases" : [ "AAA1","AAA2","AAA3"]
    }
```

**2nd Collection name is PromotionUsages:**

```
{
    "customerId": "_1234567890"
    "code": "AAA1"
}
{
    "customerId": "_0987654321"
    "code": "AAA1"
}
```

**Expected output is :**

```
{
    "code": "AAA"
    "aliasCode": "AAA1"
    "countUsages": 2
}
```

I used mongo $group and $aggregate but I am not getting required output

any help please

Thank You!!!

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: MongoDB version 2.6.7  .... ^^

Comment: You have to upgrade to 3.6 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$aliases" },
  { "$addFields": { "aliasesCode": "$aliases" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": PromotionUsages.collection.name,
    "let": { "aliases": "$aliases" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$code", "$$aliases" ] } } },
      { "$count": "countUsages" }
    ],
    "as": "aliases"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$aliases" },
  { "$project": { "code": 1, "aliasCode": 1, "countUsages": "$aliases.countUsages" }}
])
```

Output

```
{
    "code": "AAA"
    "aliasCode": "AAA1"
    "countUsages": 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you Anthony Winzlet ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
Made some changes in solution suggested by Anthony Winzlet

db.promotions.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$aliases" },
  { "$addFields": { "aliasesCode": "$aliases" }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "promotionusages",
    "let": { "aliases": "$aliases" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$code", "$$aliases" ] } } },
      { "$count": "countUsages" }
    ],
    "as": "aliases"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$aliases" },
  { "$project": { "_id" : 0,  "code": 1, "aliasesCode": 1, "countUsages": "$aliases.countUsages" }}
])
```